# How to use twilio dialer in react to call?

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-api

I am using react/redux from front-end. and back-end is a restapi in java.

backend is exposing a endpoint for calling ant its working good and call is going through, but there is no endpoint to dismiss call or any dialer.
i have search for any plugin related to react but couldn't find any relatable example or plugin for react version 16.
I am not sure how to approach the twillio call service, whether it should be done by front-end or backend.

Please specify any documentation or code example or please reply if I need to mention any other details regarding calling via dialer in twillio with react.

Comment: How are you initiating the call? You mentioned `call is going through`. Read about [ TwiMl](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) and [Twilio JS SDK installation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/overview)

Comment: My backend is exposing a url, to which I am calling a post request with phone number and other credentials.
Then the call is going forward.
I don't know if this is a good idea.
I am not using twillio sdk yet. Do I need to use the sdk anyway?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your use case, could you please elaborate further